# Magento 2 - How to call a custom HTML file like header.html and footer.html (under Magento Email or Custom Module) in any email templates?

Tags: magento2, theme, frontend, email-templates

Create separate email **header and footer** for 2 different "frontend area"

- for Customer
- for Vendor Area (seller admin panel "not admin area")

I want separate email design for both area.

right now my email template (for New Account ) is like

```
{{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}}

(default email "header.html" comes through Magento_Email::email/header.html )
```

I want to replace ***header.html*** with my ***custom-header.html***

Answer (score 0):

Create your own module named **Vendor_Module** like below:

Create a **requirejs-config.js** to the below location:

> /app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

Code for **requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
          'Magento_Email/email/header.html': 'Vendor_Module/email/header.html',
          'Magento_Email/email/footer.html': 'Vendor_Module/email/footer.html',
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Hello Sukumar,

I don't want to overwrite header.html and footer.html in my module, but I want to add new custom-header.html and custom-header.html file in email templates only.